# Github Projects?

Tags: support

Are we allowed to put projects on this site without the code?
For clarification:
Are we allowed to say something like this?

> I have a project [here](http://example.com). What do you think?

Or something like that.
I just want to do this because of a multi-file project I have.

Comment: No. See the duplicate.